# visual studio express 2013 stuck when creating project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

When i tried to created a WPF application it gets stuck on "Creating Project" and an error message occasionally pops up

"
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows desktop is waiting for an internal operation to complete. if you regularly encounter this delay during normal usage, please report this problem to Microsoft."

I've tried to search for answers and disable my antivirus but to no avail. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: what kind of addons do you have?

Comment: What did Microsoft say when you reported it to them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because answering would require physical access to the poster's machine.

Comment: the only addons i have are the Nuget Package Manager for VS and VS Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem while working on an ASP.NET project; the only thing that worked for me was building a new project and copying and pasting the code.
(It took a really long time to build the new project for some reason.)

Answer (score -3):

Restart your VS and/or your PC. VS 2013 is incredibly faster than 2010 but still has many bugs.